# App Rejection - in-app purchase

Tags: app-store-connect

My iOS application is rejected. I have changed some basics and now it's ready for the next submit for review but the In-app purchase still in review. Should I submit it again while (In-app purchase) is in review?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about iTunes Connect and not development.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can submit your app when it is in review. Make sure you have uploaded your app with proper testing.

All the best! :)